# Is there a way to create a script in goland ide that will aotumate the search function?

Tags: python, goland

I am actually searching for YAML keys like "a.b.c.d" when I press double shift and paste in the launcher a.b.c.d it gives me the file path and the line number Is there a way that I can create a python script that will automate this function because I have over 300 keys?

Comment: Like any way to automate search everywhere function?